# Use variable in R substitute

Tags: r

I have an expression stored in a variable

```
a <- expression(10 + x + y)
```

I want to use substitute to fill the expression with `x = 2`

```
substitute(a, list(x=2))
```

But this returns `a` and `a` evaluates to `expression(10 + x + y)`

Ideally `a` would evaluate to `expression(12 + y)` (or `(10 + 2 + y)`)

Is there any way to implement this behavior while using an expression stored in the variable `a` (mandated by other parts of my project)?

Comment: Maybe worth pointing out that `substitute(expression(10 + x + y), list(x = 2))` works as desired, so the question is how to use substitute on an expression stored in a variable. (Implied by your title, but nice to be explicit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `do.call`.  `substitute` won't descend into some objects but if you use `a[[1]]` here then it will work.

```
a <- expression(10 + x + y)
do.call("substitute", list(a[[1]], list(x = 2)))
## 10 + 2 + y
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do that with `pryr` if you can use an alternative (i.e. `quote` instead of `expression`):

```
a <- quote(10 + x + y)

library(pryr)
substitute_q(a, list(x=2))
#10 + 2 + y
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one snippet can be useful

```
  x <- 1; y <- 2
  a <- expression(10 + x + y)
  eval(a)
```