# r substitute with list and evaluation

Tags: r, list, lazy-evaluation, substitution

If I make this example

```
match_caller <- function(x) 1L
crazy_function <- function(x) substitute(match_caller(x),list(x=x))
crazy_function2 <- function(x) substitute(match_caller(x))

a <- 10L
crazy_function(a^2)
#> match_caller(100)
crazy_function2(a^2)
#> match_caller(a^2)
```

It seems to show that, by using substitute with a list instead of an env, the advantage is that it evals the variables before the replacement. Is that always the case ?
For now, I use `force` for safety reasons if I want the evaluation before the substitution, but is this useless ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say that you don't need `force`. As you can see from the examples in `?substitute` that's exactly how you are supposed to use `substitute`. Also, for the record, you would get exactly the same result if `match_caller <- fuction(x) 1`. so the wrapping function makes no difference.

Comment: @Edo Hi, yeah, thanks for the remark. I put match call because I want to do that for catching evaluated calls. But I'll put your notice for my simple example. I don't think the `?substitute` is clear as for whether or not it evaluates the list arg.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are already some good answers about the [substitute function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46834655/whats-the-difference-between-substitute-and-quote-in-r)/lazy evaluation, and [how to use substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780150/use-variable-in-r-substitute/986793). I just want to quote the [substitute function reference](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/substitute) (dating back to the days of the S language):

> #### Arguments
>
> expr: any syntactically valid R expression
> env: an environment or a list object. Defaults to the current evaluation environment.

So, yes, you can use a list but that's not what does the force.

It's the way you call it as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47780260/8291949) which shows again how to substitute on an expression in a value [[1]](https://rdrr.io/cran/stackoverflow/src/R/substituteExpr.R):

```
substituteExpr <- function(expr, env) {
  do.call(substitute, list(expr=expr[[1]], env=env))
}
substituteExpr(a^2, list(x=2)) # 100
```

If expr's value is an expression, substitutes in any variables (it's value, not the expression) bound in env.

Reference Details:

> Substitution takes place by examining each component of the parse tree
> as follows: If it is not a bound symbol in env, it is unchanged. If it
> is a promise object, i.e., a formal argument to a function or
> explicitly created using delayedAssign(), the expression slot of the
> promise replaces the symbol. If it is an ordinary variable, its value
> is substituted, unless env is .GlobalEnv in which case the symbol is
> left unchanged.
>
> Both quote and substitute are ‘special’ primitive functions which do
> not evaluate their arguments.
>
> Value The mode of the result is generally "call" but may in principle
> be any type. In particular, single-variable expressions have mode
> "name" and constants have the appropriate base mode.
>
> Note substitute works on a purely lexical basis. There is no guarantee
> that the resulting expression makes any sense.
>
> Substituting and quoting often cause confusion when the argument is
> expression(...). The result is a call to the expression constructor
> function and needs to be evaluated with eval to give the actual
> expression object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question wasn't about how to use substitute but about the list called in the env arg. I want to know if it's systematically evaluated and I can't find the answer in the post you show. Sorry if was a bit unclear.